# Why is Memtest still version 4.20 when there is 5.01 out since over a year?

Tags: 14.04, updates, memtest

Why is Memtest still version 4.20 when there is 5.01 out since over a year? Is it so hard to get that one into the repositories? The additional supports alone are worth it.

Answer (score 0):

Relevant bug report: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/memtest86+/+bug/1234612

Debian has 5.01 packages at http://ftp.debian.org/debian/pool/main/m/memtest86+ - they worked with my machine (Sandy Bridge i7-2700k CPU, Z77 chipset), except for the "experimental multiboot" option.